# How to convert Map<String, String> to Map<MyClass, MyOtherClass>?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a simple  `Map<String, String>`  scanMap and I want to collect and covert it to a map of type of `Map<CustomTag, CustomTagType>`.

CustomTag has 2 fields properties - key & value and I want to inject the original map key & value into it. the 2nd CustomTagType is an enum.
I want to do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> scanMap = new HashMap<>();
scanMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> CustomTag.builder().key(e.getKey()).value(e.getValue()).build(),
                        CustomTagType.SCAN_TAG);
```

but the `e.getKey()` & `e.getValue()` get 'cannot resolve method' errors.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both arguments to `Collectors.toMap` must be Functions (which are passed an element of the Stream), even if their parameter is unused.

```java
Collectors.toMap(e -> CustomTag.builder().key(e.getKey()).value(e.getValue()).build(),
                 e -> CustomTagType.SCAN_TAG)
```